# Django admin select m2m items based on their tags (item's m2m field)

Tags: django, django-admin, filtering, admin, m2m

Consider following models:

```
class Library(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

In the **Library admin** I want to add books based on their **tags**, while retaining the option to add/remove single books.

Existing options:

1. **Filter_horizontal** - filters by `__str__`, is there a way to filter by `tags__name`?
2. **Raw_id_fields** - works with any filters specified for **Book**, but you can only select 1 item. Is there a way to allow selection of more items? (checkboxes in the table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [Django-fsm](https://github.com/viewflow/django-fsm) widget and overriding its `apply_filter_val` method in  `views.py`. Now I can filter for a key `tag:tag_name` and then just select all items. I also added an option to filter for multiple words separated by a comma.

```
def apply_filter_val(self, filter_val, queryset):

    if filter_val and 'tag:' in filter_val:

        tag_tuple = filter_val.split(':')
        _, name = tag_tuple

        params = {'tags__name': name}

        new_base = queryset.filter(**params)

    elif filter_val and ',' in filter_val:
        new_base = queryset.filter(id__in=filter_val.split(','))

    elif filter_val:
        q = [Q(**{f'{field}__icontains': filter_val}) for field in self.fields]
        if filter_val and q:
            new_base = queryset.filter(reduce(self.default_operator, q))
    else:
        # Return everything if no filter_val or fields are specified.
        # This allows for a very straightforward async request, but will
        # probably not behave as expected if no fields are specified.
        new_base = queryset

    if self.obj_limit:
        new_base = new_base[:self.obj_limit]

    return new_base
```